# Packages not being created when building DotNetNuke Module

Tags: visual-studio, dotnetnuke

Am using Chris Hammond's sample CS dotnetnuke module template available at the link below:
http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/releases/view/101034

When I try to build the module in VS2012 Express the debug and release packages are not created in the packages directory. No errors are returned during the build.

Edit ----
Running the build again it has returned the following warning. Don't know if it's relevant

```
1>CSC : warning CS1607: Assembly generation -- The version '00.00.01.*' specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format
1>  DNNExplained -> C:\dnn\dotnetnuke\bin\DNNExplained.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the packages are no longer put in the packages folder and are now in the Install folder despite what all the tutorials say.

Answer (score 0):

The templates you are referring to are almost 2 years old now. The blog post announcing the VS2012 templates talks about how to use them and how they are packaged/location

http://www.chrishammond.com/blog/itemid/2616/using-the-new-module-development-templates-for-dot.aspx

You are correct that the packages are now put in the INSTALL folder, the primary reason for this was that the NUGET packages are all sorted in the PACKAGES folder now.